# grub.cfg mod? Apparent Kernel Mismatch in grub after deleting partition X (Ubuntu Studio 20.04) and copy/pasting partition Y (Ubuntu Studio 20.10)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

Good afternoon!

***READ THIS NOTE FIRST!** So, I don't know whether this will be more beneficial presented with or without the backstory / supplemental details. Therefore, if you wish to skip the backstory and get straight to the "nuts and bolts" of the question, skip to the portion in **BOLD** about halfway down the post.*

---

I'm using a Dell Latitude 7480 Laptop with a 512GB M.2 SSD which is split into several partitions. The original Windows partition that the computer shipped with, instead of deleting, I shrunk down to approx 120GB, and set off to the side (I almost never use it, but keep it on the off chance that it may come in handy once in a while). The rest of the drive is split into two partitions, each with a Linux distro. When I first got this computer, the distro that I put on the larger "primary" partition was Ubuntu Studio 19.04, with a Kubuntu 19.04 layer installed over top in order to enable me to use KDE instead of Xfce. The smaller partition was something of a "hotel" partition that I used to "audition" other distros, such as Deepin 15.11 and Ubuntu DDE (version not remembered).

This arrangement lasted me happily all the way up to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 / Kubuntu 20.04. But with the migration of Ubuntu Studio from Xfce to KDE in 20.10, the standard sudo do-release-upgrade path was blocked. As such I used that second "hotel" partition to install Unbuntu Studio 20.10, configure Plasma the way I wanted it, with all the forced blurs and transparencies that I liked, etc, install all the programs and apps that I wanted, test the functionality of all my important apps that I use for podcasting, and copied all of the files on the big 20.04 partition over to an SD card, so that I could shrink the 20.04 partition in KDE Partition Manager from the Ubuntu Studio 20.10 boot USB, enlarge the 20.10 partition, essentially swapping which partition would be the " "hotel", and replace the old Ubuntu Studio 20.04 / Kubuntu 20.04 with some new distro, be that KDE Neon, Lakka, Ubuntu Web, or something else entirely.

**--- THIS IS WHERE THE PEOPLE WHO WISHED TO SKIP THE BACKSTORY SHOULD TUNE BACK IN ---**

Since the 20.10 partition appears to be a subset of some blanket partition, it wouldn't let me enlarge it after I shrunk the 20.04 partition [*this is in KDE Partition Manager for those who are just joining us*], so instead, I deleted the 20.04 partition entirely, and copy/paste the 20.10 partition to the unallocated 244GB partition (with the command to enlarge it to fill that space). According to KDE Partition manager, all actions were successful, so I reboot the device, removed the Boot USB, and as usual, it took me back to GRUB. As expected, both Ubuntu partitions and the Windows partition were all there. But contrary to expectation, the formerly 20.04 partition was still being listed in GRUB as "Ubuntu 20.04". I chose this partition, and was greeted by the following message:

*"error: no such device: 7a97850c-d8d4-4260-8641-836c1425de6b"
error: file '/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.67-lowlatency' not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first".*

I think I have since identified the problem, but am not sure I trust myself to properly implement a solution and not break, like, EVERYTHING in the process.

Looking in grub.cfg, it appears that GRUB is still looking for kernel version 5.4.0.67 Low Latency" on this partition, but when I deleted the 20.04 partition and copied over the 20.10 partition into the space, in the boot/ folder, I only find "vmlinuz-5.8.0.25-lowlatency" and "vmlinuz-5.8.0.45-lowlatency". It seems that GRUB doesn't know to look for a newer version of the kernel.

---

From here, it seems like my options are

a) ignore the warning in grub.cfg which says never to modify it, and modify it by replacing every instance under the partition in question where it references "vmlinuz-5.4.0.67-lowlatency" with "vmlinuz-5.8.0.45-lowlatency"

b) try to find a "vmlinuz-5.4.0.67-lowlatency" file out in the wild to download and copy to /boot, hoping this will appease GRUB

c) just use the Ubuntu Studio 20.10 install USB to wipe the 244GB partition, and start from scratch configuring Plasma / installing, configuring, and testing all my programs and apps.

d) use the Ubuntu Studio 20.10 install USB to wipe 244 and apply a fresh installation, but import the settings from the properly configured "hotel" partition, by copying / replacing key folders.

---

If d) I am going to need some guidance on what folders to copy and not copy - since I'm still a Linux noob.

If c), that's a multi-hour pain in the ass project, but it's also the "safe bet" because if I've done it once successfully on the "hotel" partition, I can do it again on the main one....but man, that would suck.

If b), any idea where I can find one that's trustworthy, and is simply dragging and dropping from /home/downloads to /boot gonna work? Or, is this something I'd be better attempting in terminal? And if so, what are the commands?

If a) Is that all it'd take, just replacing the instances of kernel version names in the config script, or do I risk "super breaking" things that way by missed cross references? What about "7a97850c-d8d4-4260-8641-836c1425de6b"? Is that a value that would also need to change if I changed the kernel references in grub.cfg to avoid "cross-reference 'breakage'"?

Option C is the safest, and the one that I can do on my own without needing other help. But if there's a way to "fix" this partition without having to burn it all to the ground and start all over, that would not only save me hours of config work that I've already done just days ago, but also give this very beginner "Linux Rookie" a valuable "win" under the belt, and a tool that I can use in the future should I ever find myself in a similar situation.

I appreciate the help, everybody!

Thanks!

---

**A little bit of extra backstory for the curious - definitely not mandatory reading for the problem**

As I had referenced above, I am unquestionably a "Linux Noob". I've had success using it as a daily driver and producing my podcast on it since late April 2020, and have been able either on my own, or through successful "googling" to resolve a small number of problems and headaches along the way.

I had dabbled off and on with Linux once or twice way back in 2010 or so, and again in 2014 or so. Both instances involving whichever version of "vanilla" Ubuntu was current at the time. Both for only brief periods, neither with Linux becoming my daily driver, and both ending after only short flings, with me returning to either Mac, or Windows, or most often, a combination of the two. In or about 2018, my interest in Linux was rekindled, and I had an old AIO and a couple old laptops that had no other use anymore, so I installed various distros of Linux on them to begin playing around with it again. Still not making it my daily driver, I continued to use Windows for gaming, Mac for podcasting, and ChromeOS as my main "laptop OS", with Linux basically only being a "plaything" on the side. And yet, unlike the last two tries, even if only on the periphery of my computing life, this time....Linux stuck around.

Then in February 2020, I was able to buy this Latitutde 7480 for a great price as a refurb through Best Buy, and I decided that this would be the moment that I'd FINALLY attempt the leap to making Linux my "daily driver" and this Linux machine my "main machine", which it has been ever since. Podcasting followed the migration shortly thereafter, and while I still have that Mac Mini, I hardly ever use it anymore. The gaming PC is still Windows-only, but is not only very barely used (Nintendo Switch dominates my video game time), but I plan to install Linux on it once I replace the too-small M.2 boot SSD in it with one large enough to create a robust Linux partition while preserving the existing Windows partition. At that point, I will begin to seriously pursue "gaming on Linux" as well.

While in part for nostalgia, and in part because I like being "omni", and in part in case I ever need it, I don't think I intend to ever strive to completely remove Mac, Windows, or ChromeOS from my life entirely. So, I'm not intending to go 100% Linux, 0% Mac, Windows, and Chrome. BUT, the hope is to go, probably 85-90% Linux, and split the remaining 10-15% of my computing life with the others. At this point, we're pretty much already there, with the exception of my PC Gaming life still happening on Windows.....but as I said above....that'll change too. On balance, I'm very happy to be on Linux now, and very happy to be a part of such an amazing, and amazingly diverse and international community. Thank you for having me along for the ride. :-)

Comment: I have not read everything, and maybe should. But I would try Boot-Repair and its advanced mode to totally reinstall grub & new kernel. Be sure to be in correct UEFI or BIOS boot mode as repairs must match install. You may also need to edit fstab, but if Boot-Repair fix does not work post this: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have read your entire question and enjoyed it! You write well but to get good answers you should try to be more focused. I think where you came unstuck is understanding which of the two installs was controlling grub. If you had done a "sudo update-grub" from the 20.10 install before moving the partition you might not have had this problem. The suggestion from @oldfred should resolve that issue. The long "7a97850c- ...." thing is a UUID. Its a unique reference for a partition usually in the /etc/fstab file. I'd guess its the reference for the partition you deleted.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies, and for the good advice therein. So, it's actually the small partition that appears to be controlling GRUB. If I were to do "sudo update-grub" from the small partition [which still works, btw], do you think that may resolve the issue? What about if I do the command from the boot USB "trial environment" and then attempt the delete / copy/paste procedure again? I may just try these anyway. :-)

Comment: UPDATE: Ran "sudo update-grub" from terminal in the small partition. Here's what happened: the good news: grub now shows 20.10 in the space where it used to show 20.04, and attempting to boot from there no longer generates the grub errors. The bad news: it doesn't matter now whether you choose the grub entry for the big partition, or the small partition....it boots you into....the small partition. No matter what. Browsing in Dolphin, though, both a 244gb drive and a 110gb drive are present and accessible, and their contents are the same. But each grub entry takes you to the same place.

Comment: Post link to report from Boot-Repair, then we can see details.

Comment: Excellent! Will get Boot Repair installed and run later today, and if problems persist, I'll be back with the link. :-)

Comment: So, installed and ran boot-repair. The good news: it did not have any adverse effects on my condition. The bad news: it did not have any beneficial effects on my condition. :-) It's acting as if the big partition that I copied TO is merely a shortcut to the smaller partition that I copied FROM. Here's the link to the pastebin that boot-repair generated for me: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/R9gwcVspHg/ I'll take no further action til you guys have had a chance to review the output from boot-repair and advise. But what I'm kinda wondering is if I shouldn't just redo the partition delete/ copy.

Comment: Hey! So, I thought I'd just followup on this and see if anyone had had a chance to have a look at the pastebin link and if it revealed anything of value to solving the issue to them. :-)

Comment: UPDATE: we may consider this question closed, everyone. I got tired of waiting, so I just overwrote the 244gb partition with a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 21.04. I did this yesterday, and it's up and running well. It also had no averse impact on the 20.10 partition which I'll eventually replace with KDE Neon. Today, I read about the potential pitfall involving the big EFI bug in 21.04. Apparently, I lucked out on that one, as I not only successfully installed it on my Dell Latitude 7480, but also successfully created a 21.04 partition on my DIY Gaming PC. Anyway, case closed. I'm good now.